# Can the USA president use military force against his/her own citizens without approval?

Tags: united-states, president, military, civil-rights

Can the USA president use military force against his/her own citizens without approval?

Comment: Where? Approval form who?

Comment: @DrunkCynic I guess from God who just blessed.

Comment: ***can***, or ***may***?

Comment: Domestically?  Or on foreign soil?  This question could use more fleshing out.

Answer (score 7):

Depends what is mean by 'approval', but there is precedent here of Obama ordering extra judicial execution of US citizens - e.g.

https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/feb/05/obama-kill-list-doj-memo

In any case, regardless of whether a given course of action is legal or not, there are no mechanisms other than perhaps the conscience of individual members of the armed forces for the military to disregard any order given by the President, who is Commander-in-chief.

Comment: In theory, if it is illegal, Obama could have been impeached and then prosecuted.  Of course, that has never happened in the history of the United States, but the constitution supports it as a mechanism or option.

Comment: An impeachment couldn't stop an unapproved use of force from occurring, it can only retrospectively result in a president being dismissed. Note that a successful impeachment requires a 2/3rds majority vote in the senate, which would mean 67 senators.